# How to embed fonts in a Microsoft Store Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, installation, desktop-application

I'm developing a C# desktop application with Visual Studio 2019. I have a WPF application with some custom fonts and I don't know how to install them for every customer that downloads my application from Microsoft Store.
I've tried many things but I can't find a way to install the font files in an accessible folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to package Fonts in WPF project.

1.[Adding Fonts as Content Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#adding-fonts-as-content-items)

2.[Adding Fonts as Resource Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#adding-fonts-as-resource-items)

3.[Referencing Font Resource Items from Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#referencing-font-resource-items-from-code)

Did you follow any method above?

Comment: I'd like to know in which file I have to insert the code in those linked pages.

Comment: @Gioele Allievi It should be under the folder of your project which like `ProjectName.csproj`.